# iOS Swift ReloadData on UITableView does not refresh UICollectionView inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView Controller class, and inside of it is a String array.
The Table view has 1 cell prototype and in it a UICollectionView with 1 cell prototype.

The CollectionView is populated by passing the array into the tableview cell, which is a UICollectionView Delegate and DataSource.

When I make changes to the array inside the TableViewController, and call self.tableView.reloadData(), the CollectionView inside the cell does NOT update.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

EDIT:

Code in TableViewController:

```
@IBAction func addToArrayAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.testArray.append("Ant-Man")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    var testArray = ["Guardinas", "Iron Man", "Avengers", "Captain America"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionContainerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.testArray = self.testArray
        return cell
    }
```

Code in UITableViewCell:

```
var testArray: [String]?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.movieTitleLabel.text = self.testArray![indexPath.item]
        cell.movieYearLabel.text = "2016"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS There. And I've checked this with a breakpoint. I DOES get called again, when .realodData() is called.

Comment: you display only one cell in tableview ?

Comment: ok..you are calling reloadData for tableView when you make chenges in array and obviously table is reloading but what about collectionView reolad. You are showing data from array in collectioview so you have to reload collctionView otherwise there will be no update.

Comment: @hal9000 for now, until I make it work, yes

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Okay. Fair enough. But where do I call the collectionView.reloadData() ?

Comment: If you are using only one cell in tableView then you can reload in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of tableViiew else you can can call after calling of reloadData of TableView.

Comment: @hal9000 there is only one TABLEVIEW cell. Inside of it is a collectionView that displays cells for the array.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS calling collectionView.reloadData inside cellForRowAtIndexPath worked. Maybe submit answer so I can mark it as answered

Comment: **You can easily reload nested `UICollectionView`:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261035/5693826

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to call `reloadData` of `UICollectionView` on every update in array.
If you are using only one cell in `UITableView` then you can reload in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView` else you can can call after calling of `reloadData` of `UITableView`.

Comment: I have similar scenario : A screen has UITableView whose UITableViewCells has UICollectionView inside it. Datasource,delegate of both UITableView, UICollectionView is the viewController. Inside the CellForRowAtIndexPath: datasource method of UITableView, I am calling 'reloadData' on collectionView which is a subview of that tableview cell. 

Surprisingly, reload is happening properly only if I call [collection reloadData] inside dispatch_asyn with mainQueue. Calling reload without dispatch_async is not refreshing collectionView

Answer (score -1):

After I added cell.collectionView.reloadData(), CollectionView scrolling is so slow in my project. How to solved that kind of problem.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately!