# how to reload a collectionview that is inside a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitableview

I have a collectionView inside a tableViewCell

for example:
[image: example]
credit: [How to use StoryBoard quick build a collectionView inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867005/how-to-use-storyboard-quick-build-a-collectionview-inside-uitableviewcell)

I would like to reload the collectionView when I update information.

I have put a print in the collectionView's cellForItemAtIndexPath to test if it is being called but it isn't. How can I get the collectionView to reload?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not really an issue as "i just needed to call cell.collectionView.reloadData()"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out how! In my tableViewCell class I just need to link the collectionView as an outlet so in my tableViewCell's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I just needed to call `cell.collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: After I added cell.collectionView.reloadData(), CollectionView scrolling is so slow in my project. How to solved that kind of problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. How can we fix slow scrolling?

Comment: Try the following on the collection view - invalidateLayout and layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 6):

**Simplest Way**

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    (cell as? YourTableViewCell)?.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Or**
If you need to reload Specific `UICollectionView`

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? YourTableViewCell {
   cell.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1st on tableview cell create this function:

```
func collectionReloadData(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

then call it from

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ...

    cell.collectionReloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

create tags for collection view with `indexPath.row` of `UITableView` and create an instance of the `UICollectionView` using the tag and reload !